# How do I connect to SQL Server 2000, using vb.net 4.0 i get an exception

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2000

How do I connect to SQL Server 2000 using vb.net 4.0?

I get an exception when trying to connect to a local SQL Server 2000 instance, when using a `trusted_Connection=True` and using `System.Data.SqlClient` as the provider.

Comment: **SHOW US YOUR CODE!** and also what connection string you're using for your SQL Server database .....

Comment: Also, your version of SQL server is old enough to vote. Have you considered upgrading it?

Comment: The exception you are getting would be good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using .Net 4.0 i figured out that i need to use OleDb provider, the SQL Provider doesn't work with SQL Server 2000.